# disable app usage tracking temporily

Tags: android, android-permissions, usagestatsmanager, usage-tracking, usageevents

I am using `UsageStatsManager` to get the history of app usage records in a particular day. The problem I have been facing is, for example, when user opens Facebook at 1:00pm, and at 1:01pm, he locks the screen, with facebook still in foreground, and unlocks the screen again at 2:00pm. The app usage API shows history of 1 hour usage of Facbook, whereas I want it to show just 1 minute. Is there any way I can disable the tracking when is the screen is inactive or disable the permission temporily. I am stuck and couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by checking whether your device is locked or not and to check that there is a simple trick -

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
 if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
        //it is locked
    } else {
       //it is not locked
   }
```

So everytime you like to add time just put the above check there.

Comment: My main problem is how to disable tracking

Comment: You are calculating the time or it is calculated in some predefined method?